# Which challah does one cut on a Shabbas yom tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, challah-shabbat-bread

The Shulchan Aruch (274:1) brings down that on shabbas night you cut the bottom challah. The Rama adds that on Shabbas day and yom tov night you cut the top challah for kabbalistic reasons. What do you do when yom tov falls out on shabbas (sources please)?

Comment: Tadir VeSheEino Tadir, Tadir Kodem - Except when you only have one option. In that case we generally follow the least common occurrence.

Comment: There is no tadir so we do the least common? Source please

Comment: Not a complete answer, but consider Pesach night which falls out on Shabbos (like this year) - we broke the top matzah first, just like any other year.

Answer (score 3):

Per Rabbi Yisroel Belsky - when Yom Tov falls on Shabbos we cut the top Challa on Friday night.

Comment: Did you ask him?

Comment: No. However I heard it in a Shiur given by him a few years ago. I also was told it is printed in his Halacha Sefer.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky was asked this ( Doleh Umaskeh pg.152) exact question. He answered " Chullin 101b".  Footnote 403 explains that in Chullin 101b Abaye mentions that Shabbas is fixed and Yom Kippur is determined by bais din. Therefore we learn that Shabbas is more chashuv since it is always fixed. So Rav Chaim held that the bottom challah should be used just like every shabbas. This is also the opinion of Rav Eliyashiv and Rav Nissim Karelitz.